# golang erase symbols from console

Tags: go, symbols, erase

I want to create animation in console, when program waits. There are a lot of simple ways to do this, usually, we just draw symbols in iterations of some cycle.
Let our code be:

```
func Spinner(delay time.Duration) {
    for !StopSpinner{
        for _, r := range `-\|/` {
            fmt.Printf("\r%c", r)
            time.Sleep(delay)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is - how to remove animation, when there is no need in it from the console screen.
I tried escape sequences like fmt.Print("\b") or fmt.Printf("\r%s", "") but no result. I can not remove last symbol from screen and it concatenates with next text. How do you erase characters already printed to the console?

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: How to do this depends on which OS you're using. If you're on a Unix-like OS, something like [goncurses](https://github.com/rthornton128/goncurses) may be what you need.

Comment: Hello! My app is crossplatform, so I need to work with *nix and Windows too.

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is print a space (0x20) when you are done and that will overwrite the spinner.

ie: `fmt.Fprint(os.Stdout, "\r \r")` to put the cursor back to beginning of line after the space.

Answer (score 4):

> All you need to do is print a space (0x20) when you are done and that
>   will overwrite the spinner.
>
> ie: fmt.Fprint("\r \r") to put the cursor back to beginning of line
>   after the space.

This answer is helpful, thank you!
But, there is an important detail!
Because the spinner function has a delay, it cannot stop exactly when StopSpinner boolean flag is set to true. So, I have added a channel for synchronization.

```
func Spinner(delay time.Duration) {
    for !StopSpinner {
        for _, r := range `-\|/` {
            fmt.Printf("\r%c", r)
            time.Sleep(delay)
        }
    }
    fmt.Fprint("\r \r")
    c <- struct{}{}
}
```

Now, calling function waits, while my spinner stop.

```
var c chan struct{} = make(chan struct{}) // event marker

func callingFunc(){
  StopSpinner = false
  go Spinner(100 * time.Millisecond)

  // do something...
   StopSpinner = true

   <-c // wait spinner stop

   //do something else
}
```

In my opinion, this is the complete solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
fmt.Print("\033[H\033[2J")
```

This will put the cursor in the top left then clear the console as per this document of useful terminal commands:

https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs452/terminal.html